# How to type dynamic object with methods with dynamic argument count

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a method:

```js
const invokeActions = (target, actions) => {
  actions.forEach(({ action, args }) => {
    target[action](...args);
  });
}
```

How to type this method correctly so that the compiler shows errors for the wrong number of arguments and argument types of the called function?

Usage example:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const actions = [
  { action: 'moveTo', args: [0, 0] },
  { action: 'lineTo', args: [100, 100] },
  { action: 'closePath', args: ['error'] }, // Should return a TypeScript compiler error
  { action: 'closePath', args: [1, 2] },    // Same thing
];

invokeActions(ctx, actions);
```

The first time I tried typing via `interface` but `closePath` took `[]` and also `[number, number]`, which is not correct.

```js
interface Drawable {
  moveTo: (x: number, y: number) => void;
  lineTo: (x: number, y: number) => void;
  closePath: () => void;
}

type ActionType = {
  action: Drawable[keyof Drawable] extends (...args: any[]) => void ? keyof Drawable : never;
  args: Drawable[keyof Drawable] extends (...args: any[]) => void ? Drawable[keyof Drawable] : never;
}
```

I also tried many combinations using `infer` in `(...args: infer Args)`, tried to make `args: Parameters<T[keyof T]>` but TypeScript did the same thing or just shows errors.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLrK2w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it works as intended! How does it works? Looks so complex while I still not found it in official TS docs

Comment: The complex part of that is described in detail in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and the issue it solves at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work from the caller's side, the type of `invokeActions()` needs to look like this:

```
declare const invokeActions: 
  (target: Drawable, actions: Action[]) => void

type Drawable = {
  moveTo: (x: number, y: number) => void;
  lineTo: (x: number, y: number) => void;
  closePath: () => void;
}

type Action = 
  { action: "moveTo"; args: [x: number, y: number]; } | 
  { action: "lineTo"; args: [x: number, y: number]; } | 
  { action: "closePath"; args: []; }
```

The `Action` type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the `action` property acts as the discriminant.  That will give you the desired behavior:

```
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
if (!ctx) throw new Error(); // make sure it's not null
invokeActions(ctx, [
  { action: 'moveTo', args: [0, 0] },
  { action: 'lineTo', args: [100, 100] },
  { action: 'closePath', args: ['error'] }, // error!
  // -------------------------> ~~~~~~~
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
  { action: 'closePath', args: [1, 2] } // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
  // Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
]);
```

---

Of course you'd like to be able to compute these types instead of writing them out manually.  This is easy enough if we start with a mapping interface from the `action` properties to the `args` type:

```
interface DrawableArgs {
  moveTo: [x: number, y: number];
  lineTo: [x: number, y: number];
  closePath: [];
}
```

Then we can define `Drawable` and `Action` in terms of them:

```
type Drawable =
  { [K in keyof DrawableArgs]: (...args: DrawableArgs[K]) => void }

type Action<K extends keyof DrawableArgs = keyof DrawableArgs> =
  { [P in K]: { action: P, args: DrawableArgs[P] } }[K]
```

Note that `Drawable` is now a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `DrawableArgs`, while `Action` is a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If you augment `DrawableArgs`, then `Drawable` and `Action` will automatically update.

---

What remains is to make this work from the *implementer's* side.  This is a little tricky, because if you just annotate you'll get an error inside the `forEach()` callback:

```
const invokeActions = (
  target: Drawable, actions: Action[]) => {
  actions.forEach(({ action, args }) => {
    target[action](...args); // error
    //             ~~~~~~~
    // A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter
  });
}
```

This is happening because `target[action]` and `args` are interpreted as having two independent union types. The compiler has lost the correlation between them, so it cannot be sure you're using the arguments that actually correspond to the action; it worries that maybe `action` is, say, `"closePath"`, while `args` is `[number, number]`.  This can't happen, but the compiler loses track and can't be sure.

This lack of direct support for *correlated union types* is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  And microsoft/TypeScript#47109 (mentioned above) details the recommended approach to such cases... which is to refactor away from unions and toward [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  The idea is to use a "base" interface, and represent all your operations in terms of generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that interface and into mapped types over that interface.

Indeed the `DrawableArgs` type functions as the base interface, and `Drawable` and `Action` are the appropriate mapped types and generic indices into mapped types.  We could have started with `Drawable` and derived `Action` from it, but if we did that, it wouldn't comply with microsoft/TypeScript#47109, and the compiler wouldn't be able to follow it.

Anyway the only thing left to do is to make sure that the `forEach()` callback is actually generic in `K extends keyof DrawableArgs`:

```
const invokeActions = (
  target: Drawable, actions: Action[]) => {
  actions.forEach(<K extends keyof DrawableArgs>({ action, args }: Action<K>) => {
    target[action](...args); // okay
  });
}
```

That works because now `action` is of generic type `K`.  So `target[action]` is seen of type `Drawable[K]`, which evaluates to `(...args: DrawableArgs[K]) => void`.  And `args` is of type `DrawableArgs[K]`, so the call is allowed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJTgdzgIwDYQCCUA5gM7IDeAUMsgLYD2AbhACqMBcyA2gB7cQAV3o5oAGmQBPQSLFQAugG5ayPKHZdeA5MNETps-YpV0EeRmQgAFOGAAW3HsuoBfatTBSADinRZcAmQAXlVKXgBpZFBkAGsIKUYYNAxsfCJSMgVuAAoAOgK4TO5-NIJich4IhQBKEIA+ZGZGYAATZHdPHxRCBDBgRhAAHiiIPkgQVop4xOTSwIzyELiEpJSA9IqyRtC6cJ5raJBkau5wxH7B7mtJIvIS1IWtg4UOjqqFD2oEQbIwI+a8V6lxAZAAcnBgKxljlVGA7hAwA8NgRbn0BqDuMCMc46sFGjQ6BcMWQ8jBGFAAKKIew5HLndGDW6ZDp4gmqOjw0iInjEwYKfKFTI1JTIAD0YuQ0CgFI54sldEVSsVAD81eqVXKJchCMgyN4oBA4O07iIIOAGEI-lLgA5oMh7HBoXBkGAhN4gl5fMgKcgxMhvHAyFZ2mBGMgXYbrYGMPREdBVK4RW4PD9Qf9QICiIzQTC4QikesyhA0SCyFic7iGlRVHzQWSKdSELSRlLxuapitZkWnpl6vSIznmUtXBWQSN6mya0quSQeXWBQU8ncyCL5T7YnApInk51U79-n0+MtWowEGbwHkEIa7BBKQQ4+AcgByBBwEDMIPPmp5OdgADCgyQOML4AEytN+KjAMkOQAIRHnUDgypgugQChlJQDKUA5Gu2r0HA8R6kIhrRGAz4UCAjD-MIeB4NQmaMECOZkDkR6SDwYSDiC3DPkwrAcM+w7lrwAAMkgia8rjiJxdY8eoICaIJEbFLwACMIlicg6kSR00l7FxGI8eYlg2HY9hKSuTjPtKFLPpJkjajZUCwao2oALQeZ5XneT5XmNBq6quZKbDdMg5FgFAoAkM+0QUVREbBsAJAgAsrrhl6KDPno8jPjJOZGRYVi2A4FkqTwqmSKBknrk5Ll0BKAWNU1zUtcgQweUFyAhd6z48NlBj9YoMXAHF-xBmQSUpekaWuqFvUKM+eTULUKhfEAA)